# Why are the lights in this image changing after rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, export, camera

Why are the lights showing through droplets in star shapes? I have placed 2 lights at the back of this layer of droplets. Is it my camera settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd need way more information to try to answer this. Can you reword your question? Can you show the wireframe of the objects and the lights? Can you elaborate on the goal of the render?